# Não consigo alterar o valor que quero de um ficheiro através de um ShellScript

Tags: shell-script

```
88020:Maria Aguiar:EIB2:914256321:mguiar@gmail.com:carro:Mercedes:1414-TX-13:13:14:4
83605:Tiago Domingues:ETA4:934442913:t123@gmail.com:carro:BMW:14-TD-16:1:130:200
```

Eu tenho esse código num file, de nome `condutores.txt`.
E no script queria alterar a nona coluna por um valor que eu pretendo por exemplo.

E eu já tentei isto:

```
Numero9=$(cat condutores.txt | awk -F ':' '{print $9}' | tail -n +$1 | head -1)

NovoNumero9=$(( $Numero9+ 1 ))

sed -i 's/'"$Numero9"'/'"$NovoNumero9"'/' condutores.txt
```

Mas ele altera-me todos os locais ao longo da linha onde ocorra o `$Numero9` e eu queria que altera-se só na nona coluna, sendo as colunas divididas por `":"`.

Comment: isso aí é shellscript, não javascript rs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aconselho vc a fazer isso linha por linha, da seguinte forma:

```
# verifica o número de linhas que o arquivo tem
linhas=$(wc -l file | awk '{print $1}')
# pega o conteúdo do arquivo e coloca na variável
file=$(cat file)
# faz um laço for para subistituir linha a linha
for (( i = 1; i <= $linhas; i++ )); do
    # pega o conteúdo da linha em questão
    linha=$(sed -n $i'p' <<<"$file")
    # pega o valor da coluna em questão, da linha $i
    value=$(awk -F: '{print $9}' <<<$linha)
    # novo falor para ser substituído
    n_value=$[value + 1]
    # faz a substituição dos valores
    n_linha=${linha/:$value:/:$n_value:}
    # faz a substituição da linha no arquivo, com os novos valores
    file=${file/$linha/$n_linha}
    # escreve no arquivo
    echo "$file" > file
done
```

Esse script sobrescreve o arquivo original, para teste é aconselhado criar um novo arquivo alterando a última linha do `for`

```
echo "$file" > file
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode utilizar

```
awk -F: -v OFS=':' '$9 == "13" { $9 = "888" }1'  arquivo
```

se quiser gravar em um novo arquivo, use `> newfile` no final do comando